# I have removed my crontab. How can I recover it?

Tags: cron

I made a mistake by issuing the `crontab - r` command and the `crontab` was removed. Now, when I type `crontab -l` it is showing `no crontab for root`.

Can anyone please help me to restore the `crontab`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you've tagged a EOL/ESM release?   Releases post-EOL or covered by ESM are off-topic on this site - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Just restore from backup the deleted file in /var/cron/<username> and the reload the cron service. Or use `crontab -e` to edit the crontab, and enter the jobs from documentation or memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no `/var/log/syslog` file, you can recover the commands (but not the timings) from the `syslog` file.

use:`grep 'CRON' /var/log/syslog`

you can then figure out the timings by looking at the date-stamps.

**Credits:** [Recover cron jobs accidently removed with crontab -r](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247446/351059)

**PS:** To avoid such problems in the funture, try to add a cron to backup your crontab everyday.